Make a DIV disappear when it reaches a certain width WITHOUT JavaScript
This is a CSS-only problem, no JavaScript allowed.
I have a DIV that when it reaches a certain width, it should disappear.  @media (max-width: 1024px) {} works for the normal cases as the browser resizes.
BUT.....
There are screens that have a pop-open side panels that will squeeze the DIV into the left-half of the screen.  In this situation, I'd like the DIV to also disappear just like the @media condition above.  When the panel closes, the DIV should reappear normally.
I've tried DIV within a DIV, different display property types in combo with overflow, flex, and, of course, various @media settings.

Please show a basic minimal example which demonstrates the pop up 'squeezing' the div. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Not certain I fully understand the requirement, but are you looking for @container? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@container

This is possible using container queries.
Essentially, the selected div can only be styled on it's parent's size, not its own. You could wrap the div to be selected in another div, then when the parent reaches a certain width you could display: none the child and the parent would collapse.


.trigger {
  container-type: inline-size;
  container-name: trigger
}

.child {
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}

@container trigger (min-width: 900px) {
  .child {
    display: none;
  }
}
<div class="trigger">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>



If you run this snippet you will see a red block, if you then view it via the "Full Page" link it will be hidden.

Try using media query in css
.my_div_class{
  display: block; /* can be any thing flex, grid */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 540px /* any unit you want */) {
  .my_div_class{
    display:none;
  }
}

Above media queries state following things:
It is applied only on screens and if it between 0-540px (max width) then it applies following styles which are specified inside scope
More on media queries:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries
If you are using tailwind css
<div class="hidden md:block">
<!---contents -->
</div>

Note tailwind uses reverse order media query means you have to specify first styles small screens and then larger screens
In above example we have specified display:none to small screens and if screen width crosses specific width then it applies styles which is written inside md: scope
you can read more about tailwind here
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design

This is not what the OP wants, the element is to be hidden based on it's own size not the screen.
